# Name Change on Passport

Tags: indian-citizens, passport-renewals, us-visa

I am an international student in the United States with an Indian passport. I just had my first name on my passport due to which the visa I got had FNU(First name unknown) and my first name as my last name on my visa.  Recently I applied for a new passport to add my last name on it, so I got it. Now my new passport has my real first and last name on it but my visa is still the same. What should I do? Di I need to change my Visa name or any suggestion you guys have for me? I am a little scared because soon I am going to apply for OPT and don't want that to be an issue. Any kind of help will be appreciated
.